# Undo the actions performed by a .bat file?

Tags: windows, security, batch-file, windows-scripting

recent i search for a program "Action Mirilis" and a friend give me a .torrent link. I download it, and i read the "ReadMe.txt" file. In this file he say to run a .bat command to block comunication to mirilis server. And i want to undo this...
This is the command, please help me!

```
@echo off
DEL %WINDIR%\windefendam.log
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Blockit" protocol=any dir=out action=block remoteip=176.31.241.10
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Blockit" protocol=any dir=out action=block remoteip=91.121.143.139

SET NEWLINE=^& echo.

attrib -r %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts 

FIND /C /I "forskippingurl" %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ECHO ^127.0.0.1 thislineskipsanyemptylines>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts

FIND /C /I "mirillis.com" %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ECHO ^127.0.0.1 mirillis.com>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts

FIND /C /I "www.mirillis.com" %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ECHO ^127.0.0.1 www.mirillis.com>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts

FIND /C /I "serwer2.paka-service.com" %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ECHO ^127.0.0.1 serwer2.paka-service.com>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts

FIND /C /I "ns386119.ovh.net" %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ECHO ^127.0.0.1 ns386119.ovh.net>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts

FIND /C /I "mirillis.pl" %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ECHO ^127.0.0.1 mirillis.pl>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts

attrib +r %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
```

Comment: Because there is nothing safer than downloading files over a torrent link and following the instructions...

Answer (score 0):

You can't simply "undo" a bat-file since it is just a list of commands that are executed. Anyway it looks like this script just edits your Hosts-File and blocks some domains by directing them to localhost.

Edit the file in "%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts" using any text-editor and remove the entries that occur in the script. See this link for further instructions: https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/modify-your-hosts-file/